# Extracting polyline segment from points using QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I have a polyline from a recent hike going up and down mountain summit.  I would like to extract just the portion of this line that has the track points overlaid.

Is there away to do this without having to trace the portion of this polyline?

Also, I’m trying to do this project strictly in QGIS.

[image: green polyline of hike, with track points in red]

Answer (score 1):

You have (at least) two options:

- edit polyline layer, use cut feature to split it into parts to get desired segment.
- select points of the segment you want and use points to path tool using selected features only option.

Comment: Thanks Mat.  The points to path tool did the job.